# How to lookup the transaction fee for a particular transaction?

Tags: transaction-fees

Is it possible to lookup how much transaction fee was paid for a specific transaction?

If I check the transaction on e.g. [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/), I can see a field named "Fee", but I guess that's a sum of all fees combined in this transaction.

Comment: "Sum of all fees combined in this transaction": a transaction has only one fee, which is defined as the difference between the value of its outputs and the value of its inputs.

Comment: Okay, so a transaction is defined by its inputs and outputs. As such its not possible to see the fees applied when sending from address1 to address2, because they are all combined into one transaction?

Comment: There is no such thing as a separate fee applied to sending bitcoins from address1 to address2, if it's part of a larger transaction. A transaction sends bitcoins from one or more input addresses, to one or more output addresses. There is only one fee, like Pieter Wuille explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transaction is an atomic unit. Either the whole thing confirms or the whole thing does not confirm. The transaction fee is the result of all inputs and outputs in concert, therefore it is a property of the whole transaction and not assignable to any single created output specifically. Even when there are multiple recipients, the whole construct is "a transaction".

When you create a transaction, you define a set inputs that will be consumed, and a set of outputs that will be created and at the disposal of your recipients. The free-floating remainder, i.e. the part of the inputs' value that was not assigned to any outputs can be claimed by the miner as a transaction fee.